# What is the correct string format of the datetime with milliseconds from JavaScript to C# code

Tags: c#, javascript

This will result to an error because C# variable testDate is different in format from the JavaScript variable testDate:

jquery:

```
$.getJson
url= "/Home/GetJasonData"
testDate = '1/1/2009 10:01:01:123'
```

controller:

```
void GetJasonData(DateTime testDate)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about instead of:

```
testDate = '1/1/2009 10:01:01:123'
```

Try this:

```
testDate = '2009-01-01 10:01:01.123'
```